# Redirect to another html page after JS function (Ionic, AngularJS) - Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am building an android app in cordova tools for visual studio using Ionic and AngularJS.

I want to redirect to the another html page after my function has finished executing but I cant seem to get it to work.

Heres the function

```js
        if (id == null || id == undefined) {
            contact.save(saveSuccess, saveError);
        }
        else {
            contact.save(upSuccess, upError);
        }

        function saveSuccess(newContact) {
            id = newContact.id;
            table.insert({ contactid: id, firstname: name.givenName, lastname: name.familyName, homephone: phoneNumbers[0].value, mobilephone: phoneNumbers[1].value, email: emails[0].value });
            alert("Contact Saved.");
            window.location("#/managermenu");
        }
```

And heres my $routProvider code.

```js
droidSync.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/addcontact', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/addcontact.html',
        controller: 'managerController'
    })

    .when('/editcontact', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/editcontact.html',
        controller: 'managerController'
    })

    .when('/deletecontact', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/deletecontact.html',
        controller: 'managerController'
    })

    .when('/managermenu', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/managermenu.html',
        controller: 'managermenuController'
    })

    .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/settings.html',
        controller: 'settingsController'
    });
});
```

Im fairly new at angular and JS in general so I don't know what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the $state.
does this work?

```
function saveSuccess(newContact, $state) {
        id = newContact.id;
        table.insert({ contactid: id, firstname: name.givenName, lastname: name.familyName, homephone: phoneNumbers[0].value, mobilephone: phoneNumbers[1].value, email: emails[0].value });
        alert("Contact Saved.");
        $state.go('/managermenu');
    }
```

need a state provider too

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('managermenu', {
    url: '/managermenu',
      views: {
        'managermenu': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/managermenu.html',
          controller: 'ManagerMenuCtrl'
        }
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Replaced $routeProvider with $stateProvider routing and redirect now works perfectly! Thanks Kind Stranger

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $state use $location.

```
function saveSuccess(newContact, $state) {
    id = newContact.id;
    table.insert({ contactid: id, firstname: name.givenName, lastname: name.familyName, homephone: phoneNumbers[0].value, mobilephone: phoneNumbers[1].value, email: emails[0].value });
    alert("Contact Saved.");
    $location.path('/managermenu'); 
}
```

Route provider:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

 .when('/managermenu', {
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/managermenu.html',
    controller: 'managermenuController'
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of $state you can also use $location.path("/managermenu"); for redirecting to another state.

Comment: These needs more info to be a complete answer. How about a code example?